# A question related to convex and compact set

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness

I encounter a problem related to convex and compact set, which is stated as follows.

Whether or not the following claim is correct?

Claim: Let $C$ be an arbitrary subset of $R^n$ such that $C$ is convex and compact. For each $i = 1, \cdots, n,$ for any point in $C$, denote the largest coordinate for the $i$-th dimension by $e_{\max}^i$ and the smallest coordinate by $e_{\min}^i$. Then, the point $x = [\frac{1}{2}(e_{\max}^1+e_{\min}^1), \cdots, \frac{1}{2}(e_{\max}^n+e_{\min}^n)]^T$ belongs to $C$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the $T$ just the transpose because $x$ is a column vector?

Comment: @JohnDouma I would assume so, I have seen this type of notation before.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, $T$ is just the transpose.

Comment: am I right, that $e^i_\min = \min_{x\in C} x_i$?

Comment: @user251257  Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is in general not valid.

Let 
$$C = \{ x\in\mathbb R^3 \mid x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1, x \ge 0 \}$$ 
be the standard simplex in $\mathbb R^3$. Then, $e^i_\min = 0$ and $e^i_\max = 1$ for $1\le i \le 3$. However
$$ x^* = \frac{1}{2}(1, 1, 1)^T \not\in C. $$